# how to map slightly complicated scenario then from -> to member scenario

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, automapper

I have a `CarDto` and `Car` domain object.
Car has list of Drivers.

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int Name {get; set; }
    public ICollection<Driver> Drivers {get; set; }
}


public class CarVM
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public int Name {get; set; }
    public string DriverBadge {get; set; }
    public string[] Drivers {get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to map this objects using AutoMapper

```
 CreateMap<CarVM, Car>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Drivers, opts => {
      ... how to map here?
})
```

Comment: You need a map from `Driver` to `string`.

Comment: The question is not how to take the values from array and create a list but how to 
 do that in this scenario, inside ForMember in the AutoMapper

Comment: None of the `ForMembers` are needed. Perhaps research a little how that map would help here.

Comment: I want to move logic from the controller into this AutoMapper class. The logic how I map values from array into List of Drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is map from `string[]` to `List<>`. Simply use the below

```
 CreateMap<CarVM, Car>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Drivers, opts => opts.MapFrom(s=> s.Drivers.ToList()))
});
```

More information - [Automapper Lists & Arrays](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks for the update. what if I want inside same block to add one more Driver to the List manually (I have scenario where I want to add one more Driver depending on it's badge).

Comment: @user1765862 mapping should be only used for `src` to `dest` mapping. It has nothing to do with your business logic

Comment: None of those `ForMember` are needed. Comment them and you'll get the same result.

Comment: @user1765862 The god is here, yup indeed if `src` and `dest` have same name and type, no `ForMember` is needed

Comment: They don't have to be the same type. They just have to be 'mappable' :)